# Write to external webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I have a website written in html and javascript/jquery. How can I follow a link to another page(outside my origin--> lets pretend google.com) and automatically enter data into a form and submit it on the outside page?

For example, I want to follow a link on my page to google.com and then have the browser enter info into the search box and make a search.

Selenium?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible unless the page you are working with has set up GET or POST options that allow you to do such things. There may be other methods, but the page you are working with must first set it up and allow it.

For example, you can run a Google search by appending a q parameter to the URL like so. You can do this because Google uses GET parameters which are easy to determine.

https://www.google.com/q=stackoverflow#safe=off&q=stackoverflow

Comment: what about selenium?